# Get branch name in ASP.Net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, branch

I have a repository with ASP.Net MVC project. I want to make new branches for every new version with some name (v_1.0, v_1.1... etc.). Then somehow to get that name and display it using MVC. The goal I am trying to achieve is to have one page in my website which contains information about the branch currently published on the server. My question is not very specific becausе I am not sure if that is the best approach to achieve this so if you have different suggestions please share them.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look to [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) to update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file (do it yourself of let GitVersion do it --using a `gitversion.yml` config file where you will specify the pattern to store) during the build.

Set the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` field.
I advise you to add also the sha1 (which is more usefull to know the exact version deployed) for example with patern `sha1.branchName`

Then you you get the info with `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location).ProductVersion`;

Then you just have to process your string to extract branch name and sha1.